# Sharepoint 2013 - Export Excel disabled

Tags: sharepoint-2013

I can't export to excel from external lists. The button is disabled in the ribbon.

It works fine for other lists but for external it is disabled.

Is there a specific right to grant for external list ?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you click on an item on the list, sometimes the export to Excel is disabled until you select the list. I also would check the permissions under the External Content Types in SharePoint Designer.